# Web.API works in some deployments but returns 404 in others

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an ASP.NET WebForms app that is widely distributed. My new version adds Web.API and users have been playing with a beta. In most beta installations everything works fine, but for some installs all the Web.API calls return HTTP 404 Not Found errors. I can't figure out why the Web.API calls fail on some servers but works fine on others.

My guess is there is some kind of server configuration that is breaking the routing, but I can't figure out what it is. I've even RDP'd into one of these sites and can't find anything obvious.

This is an example API call:

GET http://site.com/api/events/27

The code:

```
namespace GalleryServerPro.Web.Api
{
  public class EventsController : ApiController
  {
    public string Get(int id)
    {
      return "Event data for ID " + id;
    }
  }
}
```

The route definitions, which are called from the Init event of a custom HTTP module named GspHttpApplication:

```
private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GalleryApi1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
  );

  routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GalleryApi2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { },
    constraints: new
    {
      id = @"\d*",
    }
  );

  routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GalleryApi3",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new
    {
    },
    constraints: new
    {
      id = @"\d*"
    }
  );

  // Add route to support things like api/meta/galleryitems/
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GalleryApi4",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new
    {
    },
    constraints: new
    {
    }
  );
}
```

The example GET above should match the route named GalleryApi2, and like I said in most installations it does.

I know WebDAV can cause trouble (405 errors), so I already remove it in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    <add name="GspApp" type="GalleryServerPro.Web.HttpModule.GspHttpApplication, GalleryServerPro.Web" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

So it all comes down to figuring out why this configuration works for some web installs and not others.

Roger

Comment: Is there any reason why you're running these in classic mode? Can you check that both machines (successful and failing) are running the app in the same mode? And BTW: should the routes not be ordered starting with the most specific one?

Comment: I'm running in integrated mode, not classic mode. And while you might be right about the ordering, that doesn't explain the 404's I'm getting.

Comment: ignore the previous comment - I thought you had config just for one of the modes but I didn't read the whole config